# How to divide between groups of rows using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have this dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame(
    name = rep(letters[1:4], each = 2),
    condition = rep(c("A", "B"), times = 4),
    value = c(2,10,4,20,8,40,20,100)
) 
#   name condition value
# 1    a         A     2
# 2    a         B    10
# 3    b         A     4
# 4    b         B    20
# 5    c         A     8
# 6    c         B    40
# 7    d         A    20
# 8    d         B   100
```

I want to group by name and divide the value of rows with `condition == "B"` with those with `condition == "A"`, to get this:

```
data.frame(
    name = letters[1:4],
    value = c(5,5,5,5)
)
#   name value
# 1    a     5
# 2    b     5
# 3    c     5
# 4    d     5
```

I know something like this can get me pretty close:

```
x$value[which(x$condition == "B")]/x$value[which(x$condition == "A")]
```

but I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this with dplyr (My dataframe is a toy example and I got to it by chaining multiple `group_by` and `summarise` calls).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

```
x %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(value = value[condition == "B"] / value[condition == "A"])
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
#
#    name value
#  (fctr) (dbl)
#1      a     5
#2      b     5
#3      c     5
#4      d     5
```

Comment: I have the same data as above, the only difference is that sometimes column "condition" does not have "A" or "B" all the time, so there's no denominator or numerator sometimes. I want to remove such rows and continue the division. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @vicky just filter them up front? x %>% filter(condition %in% c("A", "B"))

Answer (score 6):

I'd use `spread` from `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>%
  spread(condition, value) %>%
  mutate(value = B/A)

  name  A   B value
1    a  2  10     5
2    b  4  20     5
3    c  8  40     5
4    d 20 100     5
```

You could then do `select(-A, -B)` to drop the extra columns.

Answer (score 4):

Using `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(x)`), grouped by 'name', we divide the 'value' corresponds to 'B' condition by the those that corresponds to 'A' 'condition'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[,.(value = value[condition=="B"]/value[condition=="A"]) , name]
#    name value
#1:    a     5
#2:    b     5
#3:    c     5
#4:    d     5
```

Or reshape from 'long' to 'wide' and divide the 'B' column by 'A'.

```
dcast(setDT(x), name~condition, value.var='value')[, .(name, value = B/A)]
```

Comment: @user5249203 Perhaps you meant `Map` or may be you want to divide by something like `x[-1]/x[-length(x)]`

Comment: @user5249203 your comment is not clear to me in the context of this soluiton as here, we are doing a condition check for each row, i.e. the same. Did you meant `condtion == 'a'`, condition == 'b', condition == 'a', 'and so on.  IN that case, `Map` is needed i..e `Map(function(x, y) value[condtion == x]/value[condition == y], yourfirstvec_orcol, yoursecondvec)`

Comment: will try to post a Q.