# How to divide between groups of rows using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the similar data and I want the exact result as what this link states:
[How to divide between groups of rows using dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447977/how-to-divide-between-groups-of-rows-using-dplyr)

However, the only difference with my data is that sometimes column "condition" does not have "A" or "B" all the time, so there's no denominator or numerator sometimes.

```
x <- data.frame(
    name = rep(letters[1:4], each = 2),
    condition = rep(c("A", "B"), times = 4),
    value = c(2,10,4,20,8,40,20,100)
) 
x = x[-c(4,5),] #this is my dataframe
```

I want to remove rows that do not always have both A and B and continue the division. Can anyone show me how to do that based on this code?

```
x %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(value = value[condition == "B"] / value[condition == "A"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the groups which do not have "A" or "B" and then divide.

```
library(dplyr)

x %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  filter(all(c('A', 'B') %in% condition)) %>%
  summarise(value = value[condition == "B"] / value[condition == "A"])

#  name  value
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1 a         5
#2 d         5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[all(c('A', 'B') %chin% condition), 
    .(value = value[condition == 'B']/value[condition == 'A']), name]
```